# How to interpolate transform property linearly in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, interpolation

I want to "shake" an `<img>` element by constantly moving it between

```
transform: translateX(-50px);
```

and

```
transform: translateX(50px);
```

Using D3.js, like here: http://plnkr.co/edit/uJeqkizCXcPDmaJazOPa?p=preview , the circle will not even be interpolated. How can I move it smoothly?

Comment: SVG doesn't have `translateX`: http://plnkr.co/edit/zxh5yjvkqpFIeoL8Iq6L?p=preview

Comment: And <img> has no cx, cy. I ended up interpolating left and top

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. Don't forget to clear the interval.

```js
var svg = d3.select("#cont").append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 400);
 
 
 
 var circle = svg.append("circle")
 .attr("cx", 200)
 .attr("cy", 200)
 .attr('r', 10)
    .style('fill', 'black');
 
function trans(){
  circle
  .transition()
  .attr("cx",250)
  .each("end",function() {
    d3.select(this).       
      transition()         
        .attr("cx",200);   
                           
   });
}
 setInterval(function(){trans()}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify this correctly. My actual element is no circle, but an <img> tag, so manipulating cx and cy won't work. I really want to know about a translate interpolation that is as easy as possible.